# Bitbucket host key verification issue on Packagist

Tags: git, bitbucket, verification, git-clone, packagist

I have a public repository on Bitbucket and I would like to submit it to Packagist for composer purpose. However, after entering git url and submitting, The error is showing up:

```
Uncaught Exception: [RuntimeException] Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'git@bitbucket.org:xxx/xxx.git' '/home/composer/.composer/cache/vcs/git-bitbucket.org-xxx-xxx.git/' Host key verification failed. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How can I solve this issue? Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like ssh key was changed. Try to remove you `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file (or lines with bitbucket host/ip)

Comment: Currently, there is no Bitbucket related IP in my "~/.ssh/known_hosts" file. However, I am on Packagist website, how my known_hosts file may affect packagist ssh connection? I am getting the error on Packagist website after I submitted the git url of the package.

Comment: Also, here is the screenshot of the error on Packagist: http://i.hizliresim.com/z2E9Vg.png